# Numpy: Perform Multiplication-like Addition

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to define my own addition operator that takes an Nx1 vector (call it A) and a 1xN vector (B) such that the element in the i^th row and j^th column is the sum of the i^th element in A and the j^th element in B. An example is illustrated here.[image]

I was able to write the following code for the function (and it is correct as far as I know).

```
def test_fn(a, b):
    a_len = a.shape[0]
    b_len = b.shape[1]
    prod = np.array([[0]*a_len]*b_len)
    for i in range(a_len):
        for j in range(b_len):
            prod[i, j] = a[i, 0] + b[0, j]
    return prod
```

However, the vectors I am working with contain thousands of elements, and the function above is quite slow. I was wondering if there was a better way to approach this problem, or if there was a `numpy` function that could be of use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) does this already: `np.arange(1, 4).reshape(-1, 1) + np.arange(1, 4)`.

Comment: Also, never do `[[0]*a_len]*b_len`. That creates a list of `b_len` references to the same sublist. Also, the "shape" is b_len-by-a_len, whereas you seem to want the opposite. Even if you're passing the result to `np.array` immediately, it's better to write `np.zeros([rows, columns])`.

Comment: Thank you very much @WarrenWeckesser. If you add this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to numpy's broadcasting rules, you can use `a+b` to implement your own defined operator.

> The first rule of broadcasting is that if all input arrays do not have the same number of dimensions, a “1” will be repeatedly prepended to the shapes of the smaller arrays until all the arrays have the same number of dimensions.
>
> The second rule of broadcasting ensures that arrays with a size of 1 along a particular dimension act as if they had the size of the array with the largest shape along that dimension. The value of the array element is assumed to be the same along that dimension for the “broadcast” array.

[image]

Comment: Nice illustration! What do the different colors in the result (the rightmost) array signify?

Comment: There is no difference.I forgot to change it. You can regard these numbers as a same color.